# Error compiling package with custom messages

Tags: ros, cmake, message, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone,

I'm having some difficulty compiling a package that I've created with custom message.

When I run *cmake .* at the head of that package's directory, I get the error

```
 Assertion failed: file
  '/home/poofjunior/Projects/ICEX/src/external_sensor_interface/msg/data_logger_measurement.h'
 does not exist.  Message: message file not found
```

inside of the msg directory in my package, I have a file titled *data_logger_measurement.msg* but indeed, the file in question, which is the .h file, does not exist in that msg directory.

Isn't this message auto-generated?

Oddly enough, I have been able to run this package before, and I'm slightly convinced that it may be an issue with how my workspace is setup.

Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55395/error-compiling-package-with-custom-messages/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The header files for messages are autogenerated.

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

If you use catkin, also see: See http://answers.ros.org/question/55339/catkin-generate_messages-before-building-library/

For more help, explain more about your workspace setup,and post your CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-02-17**:
Aha!  It was my fault after all!  In my CMakeLists.txt for that package under the add_message_files section, I mislabeled my extension with a *.h extension instead of a *.msg extension. Thanks for the hand, though!